# Restrict Values of Type in Elm

Tags: elm

I'd like to define a type that represents a unit vector.

This is what I have currently:

```
type UVec = UVec Float Float

unit : Float -> Float -> UVec
unit a b =
  let
    norm = sqrt (a^2 + b^2)
  in
    UVec (a/norm) (b/norm)
```

While `unit` yields what I want, I have no way of ensuring that `UVec` is always a unit vector in other parts of the program. For example, I could write something like this:

`wrong = UVec 100 200`

and it would compile just fine.

Is there any way to make the `unit` function the sole constructor of the `UVec` type? Or some way to restrict values of `UVec`?

Comment: probably you could have your `UVec` type and `unit` function in a separate module, and export only the `unit` function, so that is the only thing other modules could see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place `UVec` in a module and only expose what you want:

```elm
module UnitVector exposing (UVec, unit, values)

type UVec = UVec Float Float

unit : Float -> Float -> UVec
unit a b =
  let
    norm = sqrt (a^2 + b^2)
  in
    UVec (a/norm) (b/norm)

values : UVec -> (Float, Float)
values (UVec a b) =
  (a, b)
```

I've added a function above that allows you to retrieve the values, since you aren't exposing the constructor.

Had you actually wanted to expose the `UVec Float Float` constructor, you would change the module line to something like:

```elm
module UnitVector exposing (UVec(UVec), unit, values)
```

Comment: Was hoping I could do this without adding another module, but looks like this is the way to go. Thanks!